# Python CSV Reads Rows as Columns

Tags: python

Quick question, I have a report pulled out of SAP and saved as a CSV file. I look through the CSV file to separate the data.
[image: CSV File Export]

I use the following code to parse the data into the database but need to eliminate the first row, The Header Row (Plant, Sales Order, and so no). I am struggling to skip the first header row because the columns are being referred to as rows it looks like.

```
def loadExtract():
with open('/home/bmullen/vcb/specials/upload2/OMR500_WF_PDMPLT.CSV') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')


    # cur.execute("select term, value from wfpriority")
    # priorities = dict((x[0],x[1]) for x in cur.fetchall())

    for row in reader:

        # Assign values that come straight from extract
        plantName = row[0].replace('=','')
        plantName = plantName.replace('"', '')
        salesOrder = str(row[1]).replace('=','')
        salesOrder = salesOrder.replace('"', '')
        createdate = convertDate(row[2].strip())
        pdm_spac_date = convertDate(row[3].strip())
        designid = row[4]
        productid = row[5]
        crd_due_date = convertDate(row[6].strip())
        sap_complete = convertDate(row[7].strip())
        so_line = str(row[8]).replace('=','')
        so_line = so_line.replace('"', '')
        so_line = so_line.lstrip("0")
        stylenumber = row[9].strip().replace('=','')
        stylenumber = stylenumber.replace('"', '')
        quote = row[10]
        customer = row[11]
        priority = row[12].strip().replace('=','')
        priority = priority.replace('"', '')
        csm = row[13]
        owner = row[14]
        uniqueKey = salesOrder + so_line
```

Comment: [Please, don't post images of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: next(reader, None)  # skips the header line. Not sure what you mean by "reads rows as columns"?

Comment: Just add a `next(reader)` before your `for` loop. And if you really want to make your columns into rows, you are looking for a `transpose()`  function. Both NumPy and Pandas has something like that.

Comment: Use `next(reader)` before your loop to skip over the first row. You should also take a look at the DictReader which will use the header and put the columns into a dictionary instead.

Comment: Your code can be more readable if you replace `for row in reader:` with something like `for plantName, salesOrder, createdate, ... in reader:` and then you can process the variables as you want.

Comment: Thank you all! I tried the next(reader) and it broke the whole script to our database.

Comment: Our comments are based on what you shared. If you have something else you want us to help with, update the question and append that code as well.

Comment: Have you tried using pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html). Very easy to read in CSVs (pd.read_csv(path)) and perform analysis